# Some nifty regex to parse some javascript inside HTML

Tags: php, regex

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cumulative-returns').graph({
            width: 400,
            height: 180,
            type: 'bar',
            x_label: 'Month',
            x_data: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'],
            y_label: 'Cumulative Return',
            y_data: ['5','10','15','20'],
            colors: ['666666', '000000', 'ff0000', '333366']
        });

        $('#new-returns').graph({
            width: 400,
            height: 180,
            type: 'bar',
            x_label: 'Month',
            x_data: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'],
            y_label: 'Cumulative Return',
            y_data: ['5','10','15','20'],
            colors: ['666666', '000000', 'ff0000', '333366']
        });
    });
```

What I need to do is replace `x_data` and `y_data` with new values using some nifty regex in PHP.

This is what I have come up with so far just to find the right graph but even that doesn't work.

```
$graph = "cumulative-returns";
$start_tag = '$(\'#'.$graph.'\').graph({';
$end_tag = '});';
preg_match_all("/".preg_quote($start_tag)."(.+?)".preg_quote($end_tag)."/i", $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Any suggestions would be great!

*edit:

**Please ignore the fact that its javascript, I just need to some regex to find the string between `$('#cumulative-returns').graph({` and `});` characters!**

Comment: Thats javascript/jquery not html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Perhaps?

Comment: This seems like a bass-ackwards way of getting a value into your Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\$\(\'#cumulative-returns\'\)\.graph\({([^}]*)}\);/s',$input,$matches);
```

After this, `$matches[0]` will have the values matched by the regex (including the surrounding text) and `$matches[1]` will have just the text between
`$('#cumulative-returns').graph({` and `});` characters.

Also, possibly more useful, would be:

```
preg_match_all('/\$\(\'#[^\']*\'\)\.graph\({([^}]*)}\);/s',$input,$matches);
```

After which `matches[0][n]` reflects the nth match (including surrounding text) and `$matches[1][n]` reflects the nth instance of text between `$('#[any-text]').graph({` and `});`

Answer (score 0):

create a variable to hold the x_data data
Then just manipulate that variable ...

```
var myvar = ['dec', 'may', 'whatever', 'whatver' ]
    $('#cumulative-returns').graph({
                width: 400,
                height: 180,
                type: 'bar',
                x_label: 'Month',
                x_data: myvar,
                y_label: 'Cumulative Return',
                y_data: ['5','10','15','20'],
                colors: ['666666', '000000', 'ff0000', '333366']
            });
```

Comment: No please ignore the fact that its javascript, I just need to some regex to find the string between `$('#cumulative-returns').graph({` and `});` characters!